# how to combine echo, redirection, comand output, and quotation in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to include svn version number into my C/C++ code. I found a way to do it in linux, but I also compile the code under Windows, where I don't use svn.

One way to do it would be to create a file `svn.h`, which is then included into the code. The file should contain the following line:

> #define SVNVERSION "12345M"

Here `12345M` is the output of the command svnversion. How to create such a file using bash script (or how to include the command into the Makefile)?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '#define SVNVERSION "'$(svnversion .)'"' > svn.h
```

You may have to adjust `svnversion .` so it matches exactly what you write to get *12345M*

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, SVN does keyword expansion, so you can get version numbers pasted in automatically on checkout.